# How can I calculate Assignments grade (worth 20%) and Exams grade (worth 30%) and show it in a new column as final grade?

Tags: python, pivot, pivot-table

## This is what I need to do:

1. Create a new column in the df called 'Final Score'
2. This will contain the student's combined score from all assignments and exams
3. Use this rule: each assignment is worth 20% of the grade, each exam is worth 30%

I tried converting string of assignment score to int but keeps saying cant be converted. I having problem multiplying assignment and exam grades. Error: cant multiply string and int

## Original df looks like this:

```
"""
Student ID  Assignment Name   Score
abcd1234    assignment 1      76.52
efgh5678    exam 1            67.22
abcd1234    assignment 2      88.46
...
etc.
"""
```

## I mapped the similar values and pivoted:

```
mapping = {
  'exam 1' : 'Exam 1',
  'test 1' : 'Exam 1',
  'exam 2' : 'Exam 2',
  'test #2' : 'Exam 2',
  'assignment 1' : 'Assignment 1',
  'homework 1' : 'Assignment 1',
  'first assignment' : 'Assignment 1',
  'assignment 2' : 'Assignment 2',
  'assignment #2' : 'Assignment 2',
  'HW 2' : 'Assignment 2',
}

def map_value(value):
  return mapping[value] if value in mapping else value

x = lambda value: mapping[value] if value in mapping else value

df.loc[:, 'Assignment Name'] = df['Assignment Name'].apply(x)
```

```
pivot = df.pivot(index='Student ID', columns='Assignment Name', values='Score')

print (pivot)
```

This is what the print(pivot) data looks like:

```
"""
Assignment Name    Assignment 1  Assignment 2  Exam 1  Exam 2
Student ID
abcd1234            76.52        79.23         88.46   87.31
...
```

## I need it to look like this instead:

```
"""
Student ID  Assignment 1  Exam 1  Assignment 2  Exam 2
abcd1234    76.52         79.23   88.46         87.31
efgh5678    86.11         67.22   75.45         77.20
...
etc.
"""
```

## Also, I am lost on how to go on about doing the following:

1. Create a new column in the df called 'Final Score'
2. This will contain the student's combined score from all assignments and exams
3. Use this rule: each assignment is worth 20% of the grade, each exam is worth 30%

## I need my final data to look like this:

```
"""
Student ID  Assignment 1  Exam 1  Assignment 2  Exam 2  Final Score
abcd1234    76.52         79.23   88.46         87.31   82.96
efgh5678    86.11         67.22   75.45         77.20   75.64
...
etc.
"""
```

Thank you